# Trying to get the second input to go into "outPut2.add" - Java

Tags: java

I'm trying to build a program that decodes a string:

"toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot" - input 1
"toot da wa ow rn ow blub blub it wa toot ow blub man pa ow pow toot toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot" - input 2

I just need help putting the `input2` into the `outPut2` array list so I can decode it.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class clear {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] dog = {"dog", "goes", "woof"};
        String[] fish = {"fish", "goes", "blub"};
        String[] elephant = {"elephant", "goes", "toot"};
        String[] seal = {"seal", "goes", "ow"};
        String[] cat = {"cat", "goes", "wa"};
        String[] student = {"student", "goes", "sleep"};
        String[] teacher = {"teacher", "goes", "nuts"};
        String[] russian = {"russian", "goes", "hack"};
        String[] me = {"I", "go", "eat"};

        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        List<String> sounds = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList());
        List<String> outPut1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList());
        List<String> outPut2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList());
        List<String> outPut3 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList());
        System.out.println("How many outputs do you have ?");
        int numOfInputs = Integer.parseInt(in.nextLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfInputs; i++) {
            outPut1.add(in.nextLine());
            outPut2.add(in.nextLine()); 
            // I'm trying to add the second input into outPut2. The first outPut is already going into outPut1
        }

        if (numOfInputs == 1) {
            String s = outPut1.get(0);
            String[] items = s.split(" ");
            outPut1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));  
        } else if (numOfInputs == 2) {
            String s = outPut1.get(0);
            String s1 = outPut2.get(0);
            String[] items = s.split(" ");
            String[] items2 = s1.split(" ");
            outPut1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items));
            outPut2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(items2));
        }

        sounds.add(dog[2]);
        sounds.add(fish[2]);
        sounds.add(elephant[2]);
        sounds.add(seal[2]);
        sounds.add(cat[2]);
        sounds.add(student[2]);
        sounds.add(teacher[2]);
        sounds.add(russian[2]);
        sounds.add(me[2]);

        // Removes the sounds !!! Very important!
        for (int i = 0; i < outPut1.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < sounds.size(); j++) {
                outPut1.remove(sounds.get(j));
                outPut2.remove(sounds.get(j));
            }
            System.out.print(outPut1.get(i) + " ");
            System.out.println(outPut2.get(i) + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So what's going wrong exactly? Are there any line breaks in your input?

Comment: no, I just want the second input to go into outPut2

Comment: You're calling `Scanner#nextLine()` if there are no line breaks in your input, then the first call is going to get all of it and there won't be any left to be assigned to `outPut2`.

Comment: Can you post a sample of what the full input looks like? Including the leading `int` and everything that goes into both lists?

Comment: How many outputs do you have ?
2
toot da wa ow rn ow blub blub it wa toot ow blub man pa ow pow toot toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot
toot da wa ow rn ow blub blub it wa toot ow blub man pa ow pow toot toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot toot woof wa ow ow ow pa blub blub pa toot pa blub pa pa ow pow toot


da rn it man pa pow pa pa pa pa pa pow pa pa pa pa pa pow

Comment: Yeah, if that's all one line, then everything after the `2` is going to go into `outPut1`. I'm not exactly clear on what you're trying to do, but try changing the `Scanner#nextLine()` calls to `Scanner#next()`.